# Simplification of log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, log4j2

I am testing for migration from **log4j 1** to **log4j 2**.

The following example **works correctly**.

But I would like to know if the **log4j2.properties** can be simplified, as I find it somewhat "verbose".

The idea is that all use of the **XXX** logger is recorded to the **XXX.log** file.
Likewise, all use of the **YYY** logger is recorded in the **YYY.log** file.
And everything else "**undefined**" is written over **Default.log**

As I say, it already works as I intend, but I would like to know if the **log4j2.properties** can be minimized in some way, since my real application uses about **9 loggers**.

```
package test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLog4j2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("START");

        Logger log = null;
        
        log = Logger.getLogger("XXX");
        log.debug("Running method 'main' of class 'TestLog4j2' (want to be logged to XXX.log file)");

        log = Logger.getLogger("YYY");
        log.debug("Running method 'main' of class 'TestLog4j2' (want to be logged to YYY.log file)");
            
        log = Logger.getLogger(TestLog4j2.class);
        log.debug("Running method 'main' of class 'TestLog4j2' (want to be logged to Default.log file)");

        System.out.println("END");
    }
    
}



#Definicion de propiedades reutilizables
property.APP_LOG_ROOT = C:/logs
property.PATRON_LOG_DETALLADO = %-5p: [%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS}] [%c{1}]: [%C{1}.%M.%L]: %m%n

#Definicion appender de traza a fichero Default para logs sin logger definido
appender.Default.type = RollingFile
appender.Default.name = Default
appender.Default.fileName = ${APP_LOG_ROOT}/Default.log
appender.Default.filePattern = ${APP_LOG_ROOT}/Default.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.Default.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.Default.layout.pattern = ${PATRON_LOG_DETALLADO}
appender.Default.policies.type = Policies
appender.Default.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.Default.policies.time.interval = 1

#Definicion appender de traza XXX
appender.XXX.type = RollingFile
appender.XXX.name = XXX
appender.XXX.fileName = ${APP_LOG_ROOT}/XXX.log
appender.XXX.filePattern = ${APP_LOG_ROOT}/XXX.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.XXX.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.XXX.layout.pattern = ${PATRON_LOG_DETALLADO}
appender.XXX.policies.type = Policies
appender.XXX.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.XXX.policies.time.interval = 1

#Definicion appender de traza YYY
appender.YYY.type = RollingFile
appender.YYY.name = YYY
appender.YYY.fileName = ${APP_LOG_ROOT}/YYY.log
appender.YYY.filePattern = ${APP_LOG_ROOT}/YYY.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.YYY.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.YYY.layout.pattern = ${PATRON_LOG_DETALLADO}
appender.YYY.policies.type = Policies
appender.YYY.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.YYY.policies.time.interval = 1

#Definicion logger de traza XXX
logger.XXX.appenderRef.XXX.ref = XXX
logger.XXX.name = XXX
logger.XXX.level = DEBUG
logger.XXX.additivity = false

#Definicion logger de traza YYY
logger.YYY.appenderRef.YYY.ref = YYY
logger.YYY.name = YYY
logger.YYY.level = DEBUG
logger.YYY.additivity = false

#Definicion rootlogger
rootLogger.level = DEBUG
rootLogger.appenderRef.Default.ref = Default
```

Comment: Are you sure you still want ti stick with properties file? The common way is an XML config file, which is IMHO easier to read and you don't have to repeat so many parts.

Comment: Using log4j2.xml I get a conflict with xerces libraries used by my project

Comment: Seems we are talking about really ancient software because the necessity to include xerces libraries I think I last had with Java 7.

Comment: You are right, its some kind of Java legacy project